# A system call like scandir()

Tags: file, rhel, directory

I want to scan a directory for all and only `files` entries. When I am trying to do this I am getting all directory listing `/etc, /home, /selinux` etc... but not files listing.

Is there any system call which returns only files listing, not directories.

Or if anyone can suggest me hot to check only files not directory in side a directory.

for example...

I want to access all files in side this folder `/home/username/folderone/foldertwo/finalfolder`. Inside folder scan all files.

Comment: `scandir` returns everything (that you don't filter out), not just directories. It's not recursive though. Is that your issue?

Comment: @Mat...Thanks. I got it.

Comment: What context are we talking about here? In C\C++ or in a shell such as Bash?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all regular files in the current directory without recursion you can use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -le 'print for grep {-f} <*>'
```